# Google APIs Node.js Client with express and webpack

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I'm learning how to use express. My final goal is to build a dashboard with react/d3 and some data from Google Analytics. Right now I have a local project including react-webpack-babel. I want to use [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) to call Google Analytics. I'm trying to follow this tutorial : http://www.2ality.com/2015/10/google-analytics-api.html but I can't run my project. Got a bunch of error in my terminal, here is the main one :

```
[1] /Users/myname/Desktop/reactdashboard/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/transformation/file.js:91
[1]         throw new ReferenceError("Unknown option: " + key);
[1]         ^
[1] 
[1] ReferenceError: Unknown option: presets
[1]     at File.normalizeOptions (/Users/myname/Desktop/reactdashboard/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/transformation/file.js:91:15)
[1]     at new File (/Users/myname/Desktop/reactdashboard/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/transformation/file.js:70:22)
[1]     at transform (/Users/myname/Desktop/reactdashboard/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/transformation/index.js:18:14)
[1]     at Object.transformFileSync (/Users/myname/Desktop/reactdashboard/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/api/node.js:74:10)
[1]     at compile (/Users/myname/Desktop/reactdashboard/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:73:20)
[1]     at normalLoader (/Users/myname/Desktop/reactdashboard/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:119:14)
[1]     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/myname/Desktop/reactdashboard/node_modules/babel/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:132:7)
[1]     at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
[1]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
[1]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
```

so here is my ga.js file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env babel-node
import google from 'googleapis';
var fs = require('fs');
import key from '../client_id.json';

const VIEW_ID = 'ga:80220323';

    let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
      key.'mail@domain.com', null, key.'myKey',
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'], null);
    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      let analytics = google.analytics('v3');
      queryData(analytics);
    });

   function queryData(analytics) {
      analytics.data.ga.get({
        'auth': jwtClient,
        'ids': VIEW_ID,
        'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
        'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
        'max-results': 10,
      }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
              return;
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
          });  
        }

module.exports = {
  ???
};
```

Here is my server.babel.js file :

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));
app.use('/', express.static('src'));

var ga = require('./src/routes/ga');

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

//templating engine
app.set('views', './src/views');      
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/gadata', ga.queryData());
```

Please if my questions isn't clear enough, help me to improve so I can find my way.

edit#1 :

here is my babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

edit #2:

and my webpack.config :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './public/client.js',
  output: {
    path: './public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'       
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'] 
  },
node: {
  fs: "empty",
  net: "empty",
  tls: "empty",
}
};
```

Comment: Please show us the specific errors you are getting so we know how exactly to approach your problem. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I edit my question and add the error.

Comment: can you check your babel version?

Comment: also, please post you babelrc file

Comment: babelrc edit. and here is my package Json for babel dependencies :     `"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.10.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0"`

Comment: sorry. can you finally let me see the webpack config?

Comment: try: npm install --global babel-cli

Comment: Ok Babel-Cli installed but got the same error and webpack config added in my question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121793/discussion-between-simon-breton-and-franz-palngipang).

Comment: try to install babel-core  6.8.0

Comment: done. but I don't see babel-core in my package Json.